# CORS errors with Symfony 4 & Nelmio CORS Bundle

Tags: symfony, cors

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting CORS issues with my Symfony 4 API application I've just deployed to my Apache server and can't make any sense of the issue.

**config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml**

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

**.env**

```
...
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=/*/
...
```

All responses from requests I make from my `localhost` front-end application to that API contain no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and I get the standard error;

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-api.com/foo' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

No special headers are being sent and for now I've set the allowed origin regex to "all" so I can't work out what is causing issue here. I've even checked within the cache to ensure the origin is being correctly pulled from the env variables, which it is. If other context/file content is required to assist please let me know!

Comment: Are you sure about your CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN var. Did you try CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=* ?

Comment: @FlorianHermann the variable is interpreted as a regular expression, however yes I've tried both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue, and although on the surface it appeared to be related to the CORS configuration, it was actually misconfiguration of the project on the server.

TL;DR is that the project was missing a `.htaccess` file which I didn't require in development due to using Valet - following the instructions [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) resolved the issue.

Comment: And what is the content of the .htacess , ?

Comment: @ALFA it's in the link within the answer

Answer (score 1):

I always try to be a bit more specific for allowing CORS like:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^http://(.*:8080|localhost:4200)$
```

what you could try if you really want to enable all origins would be something like:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've opted to use a regular expression (`origin_regex: true`) but not provided valid pattern.

If you want to use `origin_regex: true` then you should specify a valid pattern such as `.*` or `^.*$`.

If you don't want to use a regular expression then omit the `origin_regex` setting (or set it to `false`) and just use `*` as your `CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN` value.

Comment: Even with this suggested change it makes no difference, I'm assuming there's something unrelated causing this, which is bizarre.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need nelmio?

You can have simple event listener(on [kernel.event_subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-event-subscriber)) adding these headers.

```
namespace App\EventListener\HttpKernel;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class CorsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onResponse'
        ];
    }

    public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $filterResponseEvent)
    {
        $response = $filterResponseEvent->getResponse();
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
}
```

Register it as kernel.event_subscriber

```
    app.http_kernel.cors_subscriber:
        class: App\EventListener\HttpKernel\CorsSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: I'll want to be more restrictive of CORS when using the application more seriously in a production mode, for now I'm only attempting to confirm a functional first deployment which I can't do even when being as unrestrictive as possible